# Firestore. How to create query based on user conditions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to create query. I'm using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. Initialising adapter I got error:

> FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.

How I can create index if eventId in my case is dynamic value?

I'm sure this is basic thing, cause I'm doing all according to manual. As I read in the documentation, sets of data should have crossing sets of keys ie {dataId, true} in both events and users in my case. Please help me where to go for solution.

```
     Query query = mFirebaseFirestore.collection(EVENT_INFO).document(eventId)
                .collection(USERS)
                .whereEqualTo(FIELD_AGE, guestAge)
                .whereEqualTo(EVENTS_ATTENDED + "."+ eventId, true)
                .orderBy(FIELD_FAMILYNAME, Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that moment there is no such an options to do things beautifull with Firestore. So we should think of hiding items based on custom criteria inside `onBindViewHolder` method in our `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. Like follows:

```
                   protected void onBindViewHolder(GuestHolder holder, int position, GuestItem guest) { 
                    Map<String, Boolean> map = guest.getEventsAttended();

                            if (map != null && map.containsKey(eventId)) {
                                holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            } else {
                                holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
                           }}
```

Hope this helps someone.